# datatables filter with statesave cause issue when headers order changed

Tags: javascript, datatables

I have an `html` page and some javascript code.  Below is my working `html`:

```
<table class="table table-hover" id="gridHelpDesk">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th class="color-white">Employee ID</th>
            <th class="color-white">Name</th>
            <th class="color-white">Email</th>
            <th class="color-white">Survey Status</th>
            <th class="color-white">Start Date</th>
            <th class="color-white">Completed Date</th>
            <th class="color-white">Survey Link</th>
            <th class="color-white">Reactivate Link</th>
            <th class="color-white">Delete Responses</th>
            <th class="color-white">Create New Link</th>
            <th class="color-white">Send Reminder</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th class="filter">Search Employee ID</th>
            <th class="filter">Search Employee Name</th>
            <th class="filter">Search Employee Email</th>
            <th></th>
            <th></th>
            <th></th>
            <th></th>
            <th></th>
            <th></th>
            <th></th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
</table>
```

Here is my `javascript` code:

```
    var dtGridHelpDesk;
    var EmployeeName;
    var EmployeeID;
    var Email;

    $(document).ready(function () {
        InitializerHelpDeskGRID()
    })

    function InitializerHelpDeskGRID() {

        $('.filter').each(function () {
            var title = $(this).text();
            var classForFilter = $(this).text();
            classForFilter = classForFilter.split(' ').join('');

            $(this).html('<input type="text" class="form-control input-sm ' + classForFilter + '" placeholder="' + title + '" onclick="event.stopPropagation()" onkeypress="event.stopPropagation()" />');

        });

        dtGridHelpDesk = $('#gridHelpDesk').dataTable({
            scrollCollapse: true,
            serverSide: true,
            ajax: {
                url: '@Url.Content("~/Home/GetHelpdeskData")',
                data: SearchHDParams,
                dataSrc: HDGridDataBound,
                type: "POST"
            },
            processing: true,
            processing: "<span class='glyphicon glyphicon-refresh glyphicon-refresh-animate' />",
            bDestroy: true,
            select: true,
            paging: false,
            bLengthChange: false,
            info: false,
            ordering: false,
            searching: true,
            stateSave: true,
            stateLoadParams: function (settings, data) {
                if (data.order) delete data.order;
            },
            columnDefs: [
            {
                targets: 0,
                data: "EmployeeID",

            },
            {
                targets: 1,
                data: "EmployeeName",
            },
            {
                targets: 2,
                data: "Email",
            },
            {
                targets: 3,
                data: "SurveyStatus"
            },
            {
                targets: 4,
                data: "StartedDate"
            },
            {
                targets: 5,
                data: "CompleteDate"
            },
            {
                targets: 6,
                data: "PositionNumber",
                render: function (data, type, full, meta) {
                    return '<button class="btn btn-info btn-sm" onclick="CopyLink(this, \'' + full.SurveyLink + '\')"> Copy </button>'
                }
            },
            {
                targets: 7,
                data: "PositionNumber",
                render: function (data, type, full, meta) {
                    return '<button class="btn btn-success btn-sm" onclick="ReActivateLink(this, \'' + full.PositionNumber + '\')"> ReActivate </button>'
                }
            },
            {
                targets: 8,
                data: "PositionNumber",
                render: function (data, type, full, meta) {
                    return '<button class="btn btn-warning btn-sm" onclick="DeleteResponses(this, \'' + full.PositionNumber + '\')"> Delete & ReActivate </button>'
                }
            },
            {
                targets: 9,
                data: "PositionNumber",
                render: function (data, type, full, meta) {
                    return '<button class="btn btn-default btn-sm" onclick="UpdateLink(this, \'' + full.PositionNumber + '\')"> Create </button>'
                }
            },
            {
                targets: 10,
                data: "PositionNumber",
                render: function (data, type, full, meta) {
                    return '<button class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" onclick="SendReminder(this, \'' + full.PositionNumber + '\')"> Send Reminder </button>'
                }
            }]
        });

        var state = dtGridHelpDesk.api().state.loaded();
        if (state) {
            dtGridHelpDesk.api().columns().eq(0).each(function (colIdx) {
                var colSearch = state.columns[colIdx].search;
                if (colSearch.search) {
                    $('input', dtGridHelpDesk.api().column(colIdx).header()).val(colSearch.search);
                }
            });

            dtGridHelpDesk.api().draw();
        }

        dtGridHelpDesk.api().columns().eq(0).each(function (colIdx) {
            $('input', dtGridHelpDesk.api().column(colIdx).header()).on('keyup change', function () {
                dtGridHelpDesk.api()
                    .column(colIdx)
                    .search(this.value)
                    .draw();
            });
        });
    }

    function SearchHDParams(d) {
        d.EmployeeName = $('.SearchEmployeeName').val()
        d.EmployeeID = $('.SearchEmployeeID').val()
        d.Email = $('.SearchEmployeeEmail').val()
    }

    function HDGridDataBound(response) {
        if (response.IsSuccess == true) {
            return response.gridData;
        }
        else {
            toastr.error("Something went wrong, Please try again after some time.");
        }
    }
```

The strange thing is that my `javascript` code fails if I change the order of my Header rows in the `html`.  For example, if I swap the `search` header with the text in the `html`, as demonstrated below, then my `javascript` code fails.

```
 <table class="table table-hover" id="gridHelpDesk">
    <thead>     
        <tr>
            <th class="filter">Search Employee ID</th>
            <th class="filter">Search Employee Name</th>
            <th class="filter">Search Employee Email</th>
            <th></th>
            <th></th>
            <th></th>
            <th></th>
            <th></th>
            <th></th>
            <th></th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>      
        <tr>
            <th class="color-white">Employee ID</th>
            <th class="color-white">Name</th>
            <th class="color-white">Email</th>
            <th class="color-white">Survey Status</th>
            <th class="color-white">Start Date</th>
            <th class="color-white">Completed Date</th>
            <th class="color-white">Survey Link</th>
            <th class="color-white">Reactivate Link</th>
            <th class="color-white">Delete Responses</th>
            <th class="color-white">Create New Link</th>
            <th class="color-white">Send Reminder</th>
        </tr>          
    </thead>
</table>
```

Why is this happening, and how can I fix it?  I do not understand why swapping the order of items in my `html` would break my javascript like this, nor do I see a clear way to resolve the issue.

I have already tried many possible solutions, but as I am loading data based on my function (SearchHDParams), the `javascript` over-writes the state.  Therefore, none of my solutions so far have worked.  Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Can you make a fiddle of your code, a working example

Comment: Not clear what is going wrong.  Can you clarify what the problem is?  What is happening that should not be happening, or, what isn't happening which should be happening?

Comment: (I think you literally just need to change the column specifier in your JS code, but without more information it's hard to say.)

Comment: @MaxvonHippel I tried, but it not helped me..

Comment: @MaxvonHippel thanks for edit..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### CAUSE

Your code `dtGridHelpDesk.api().column(colIdx).header()` returns `th` cell from bottom header row which doesn't contain `input` elements after you switched order of header rows.

#### SOLUTION 1

The way your code is written, the easiest solution is to use the [`orderCellsTop`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/orderCellsTop) option. It will make DataTables return `th` cell from top header row when you call [`column().header()`](https://datatables.net/reference/api/column().header()) API method.

```
"orderCellsTop": true
```

It will not cause any problems now because you have ordering disabled. If you decide to enable ordering later, this solution will cause issues because your top row has search boxes and not column headings.

#### SOLUTION 2

Better solution is to replace code:

```
$('input', dtGridHelpDesk.api().column(colIdx).header())
```

with:

```
$('input', $('th', dtGridHelpDesk.api().table().header()).eq($(dtGridHelpDesk.api().column(colIdx).header()).index()))
```

This code looks for search boxes in `th` cells of both header rows, not just bottom one.