# datatables search not working server side

Tags: jquery, datatable

I have set up datatables in my code and I am getting the values from the server using the following code for jquery.

The code I am using is as below:-

```
var dt = $(".ajaxTable").DataTable({
            ajax: getData,
            // lengthChange: false,
            serverSide: true,
            processing: true,
            searching: true,
            "responsive": true,
            "filter":true,
            "sDom": '"<"right_fter"<"serch_xop"fp>>t<"bottom_tb_Pl"il><"clear">',
            "bPagingType": "first_last_numbers",
            // "bPaginate": false,
            order: [],
            columnDefs: [
            { orderable: false }
            ],
            language: {
                paginate: {

                },
                "search": '',
                "searchPlaceholder":'Search property…'
            },
            pageLength: pageSize,
            "columns": [
                {
                    render: propertyFavorite, className: "column-center"  },
                { "data": "RoofLinkText", className:"key", render: editLink },
                { "data": "Address" },
                { "data": "City" },
                { "data": "State" },
                { "data": "Code" },
                { "data": "Market" },
                { "data": "CompanyName" },
                { render:actionLink, orderable:false, className:"actions" }
            ],
            order: [[1, "asc"]],

        });
        $(".dataTables_wrapper .right_fter").prepend('<div class="title_bar">Properties</div>');

        dt.columns().iterator('column', function (ctx, idx) {
            $(dt.column(idx).header()).append('<span class="sort-icon" />');
        });
```

But when I am trying to search for the option the datatables is not able to detect a change in the search column.

**EDIT**

```
var getData = rm.configData({
            tableSel: '.ajaxTable',
            url: listUrl,            
            formatter: function (o) {
                //console.log(o.TotalRecords);
                return {
                    "recordsTotal": o.TotalRecords,
                    "recordsFiltered": o.TotalRecords,
                    "data": o.Properties

                }               
            }
        })
```

**SERVER SIDE CODE**

```
public ActionResult List(
            string sort = "RoofName",
            bool sortAsc = true,
            string search = null,
            int page = 1,
            int pageSize = 10,
            string company = null,
            string region = null,
            string market = null,
            string message = null)
        {
            Domain.Models.User user = Account.AccountManager.GetCurrentUser();

            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(region) && !String.Equals("all", user.Region, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
                region = user.Region;

            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(market) && !String.Equals("all", user.Market, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
                market = user.Market;

            var model = new PropertySearchViewModel();
            model.Sort = sort;
            model.SortAsc = sortAsc;
            model.Search = search;
            model.Page = page;
            model.PageSize = pageSize;
            model.FilterCompanies = company;
            model.FilterRegions = region;
            model.FilterMarkets = market;

            int[] companyIDs = ParamHelper.ToIntArray(model.FilterCompanies);
            string[] regions = ParamHelper.ToStringArray(model.FilterRegions);
            string[] markets = ParamHelper.ToStringArray(model.FilterMarkets);

            if (model.Page == 0) model.Page = 1;

            int totalRecords;
            IEnumerable<RM.Domain.Models.Search.PropertySearch> properties = _roofData.Search(
                page,
                model.PageSize,
                out totalRecords,
                model.Sort,
                model.SortAsc,
                model.Search,
                companyIDs,
                regions,
                markets,
                user.UserID,
                user.AssetManager,
                user.PropertyManager,
                user.RoofGroup,
                null);


            model.Properties = SearchPropertyModel.FromProperty(properties);
            model.TotalRecords = totalRecords;

            if (model.Page > model.TotalPages)
                model.Page = 1;

            JsonResult result = Json(model, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            return result;
        }
```

Can you please help me with that?

Regards
Abhishek

Comment: Add getData() for reference..

Comment: @Bharat Added the code for more details

Comment: are you using default search of DataTable? what happens when you search something, are you getting hit on Server side method?

Comment: @Bharat yes. I am using default search. I am not getting any value on server side. It is coming as null.

Comment: see my question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43892564/datatables-filter-with-statesave-cause-issue-when-headers-order-changed, change is only that I am using my own search while you are using Default one. let me know if you not understand anything on it..

Comment: @Bharat not helpful.

Answer (score 3):

So Firstly, in order to make the DataTable server-side code reusable as well as reduce the amount of code, ideally you would use a Model for the parameters received which allows you to navigate the received data easier.

Therefore, a Model containing the following structure:

```
public class DataTableRequestModel
{
    public int draw { get; set; }
    public int start { get; set; }
    public int length { get; set; }
    public List<Column> columns { get; set; }
    public Search search { get; set; }
    public List<Order> order { get; set; }
}

public class Column
{
    public string data { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public bool searchable { get; set; }
    public bool orderable { get; set; }
    public Search search { get; set; }
}

public class Search
{
    public string value { get; set; }
    public string regex { get; set; }
}

public class Order
{
    public int column { get; set; }
    public string dir { get; set; }
}
```

Full list of parameters in here: https://datatables.net/manual/server-side

As for the controller, in order for the search to work, I had to use POST request, as with GET request, the search[value] was remaining null.

Therefore as a controller, you could use something like:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult GetMyList (DataTableRequestModel model)
```

And get the values from the model for the generic search by using the model.search.value or regex or by columns.

Additionally, you can check out this [post](https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/40690/sample-implementation-of-serverside-processing-in-c-mvc-ef-with-paging-sorting-searching) which is quite helpful.

Hope this helps, ideally you would use the debugger in order to check the actual data you're receiving what data you're getting exactly.